# How to add the time of a post to the list of posts on the administration page?

Tags: posts, admin

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I haven't been able to figure it out. What I'd like to do is add the time a post is scheduled to the date stamp on the list of posts. I know this means modifying the columns, and there's a way to do it that seems fairly simple. Has anyone done this, and can you suggest some code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_columns', 5);
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_columns', 5, 2);
function posts_columns($defaults){
    $defaults['your_date_col'] = __('Date');
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_columns($column_name, $id){
    if($column_name === 'your_date_col'){
        echo the_date();
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, works like a charm. Posted a followup question.